# How to update the multiselected checkbox values in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

multiselected  checkbox  [image]

I want to update the values in database. Please help me. The value is coming from the view like array in controller

```
        $user=CmsUser::find($id);

        $data=$req->all();

    if(count($req->input("involved"))!= 0){
           $values=$req->input('involved');

           foreach ($values as $value){
             $subscriberNewsletter= CmsSubscriberInvolve::where('subscriber_id',$id)
             ->update(["value"=>$value] );
           }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide some code for us?

Comment: Thanks for providing your code. Unfortunately, it still needs a bit of work to be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to work with.